# Check the expression value in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a div which needs to be displayed if one of the radio button is selected else hidden. What I am trying is :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
           <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="1"/> One</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="2"/> Two</label>
           <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioValue" value="3"/> Three</label>
           <div>currently selected: {{radioValue}}</div>
           <div ng-show = "{{radioValue}}=='1'">
               <p> Metric Test values</p>
               <b> Src: Value1 </b>
               <b> Metric1: Value2 </b>
               <b> Density: Value3 </b>
           </div>
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
  </body>
```

However I am not able to display the div irrespective of the combobox selected or not

Comment: try ` ng-show = " radioValue=='1' "`

Comment: Just `ng-show="radioValue"` should suffice. Angular doesn't need braces inside `ng-show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `{{}}` for `radioValue` for `ng-show` like below

```
<div ng-show = "radioValue=='1'">
```